# String input from user in C

Tags: c

What I'm trying to archive is that,

Step 1: Ask user if he/she wants to go on either method 1 or 2(input the corresponding integer)

Step 2.1: If method 1, input the string

Step 2.2: If method 2, read the file

The issue is that step 1 works however, when it goes to step 2 it breaks. I think after I key in the integer, the "enter" button is saved in the buffer and thus causes the program to break. I searched but I couldn't find a way to get passed this.

Also on step 2.2: the string is read from the file however all the things after the whitespace is ignored.

Any idea I could do to get through it?

```
int main()
{
int i,input1;
char str[STRSIZE], buf[1024];
FILE *fr;


printf("Would you like to?\n");
printf("Option 1. File 2. Input:");
scanf("%d",&input1);


switch(input1)
{
    case 1:
        fr=fopen("foo.txt","r+");
        fscanf(fr,"%s",str);
        printf("String from the file %s",str);

        break;


    case 2: printf("Enter the String: ");
        if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)!= NULL)
        {
            char *newline = strchr(str, '\n'); /* search for newline character */
            if ( newline != NULL )
            {
                *newline = '\0'; /* overwrite trailing newline */
            }
        }


}
```

}

Comment: Now, you should debug your code, add prints statements or use GDB to inspect values.

Comment: On "step 2.2", you should read the documentation of the methods you are using, more specifically the meaning of "%s" in the format string (it is doing exactly what you told it to do), and look up the other things you could use in that format string instead.

Comment: `scanf("%d%*c", &input1);`